# Flutter download flie in stream for progress control for iOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, download, stream

This code work well at Android and at Android Studio framework, in same time if code deployed to iOS devices i receive error

I reciving
*OS (Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 1073741840 bytes.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Out of )*

```
  await response.stream.listen(
      (List<int> newBytes) {
        bytes.addAll(newBytes);
        final downloadedLength = bytes.length;
        _progress = (downloadedLength / contentLength!) / 2 * 100;
        if(bytes.length>96607667)
          {
            print (bytes.length);
          }
        if(newBytes.length>96607667)
        {
          print (newBytes.length);
        }
        fileInfo.progress = _progress;
      },
  cancelOnError: true
).asFuture();
```

size of file is 96607667
i can't understand - what i do wrong?

Comment: why would you want to `bytes.addAll(newBytes)`? sooner or later you will get out of memory for large files

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem in the following way

```
 late Uint8List bytes;
  int received = 0;

  var completer = Completer<Uint8List>();

  var sink = ByteConversionSink.withCallback(
          (bytes) => completer.complete(Uint8List.fromList(bytes)));

  response.stream.listen(
          (List<int> newBytes) {
            sink.add(newBytes);

            received += newBytes.length;
            fileInfo.progress = (received / contentLength) / 2 * 100;
          },
      onError: completer.completeError,
      onDone: sink.close,
      cancelOnError: true);
```

Comment: all you need is `response.stream.pipe(out)` where `out = outFile openWrite()` - no need for `listen`, `close`, `ByteConversionSink`, writing the buffer to file etc

Comment: more on `Stream.pipe` method here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/pipe.html